# Sbt Unresolved Dependencies (Not a valid command: gen-idea)

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-idea

I'm trying to get sbt to generate Intellij IDEA project files using the sbt-idea plugin as described [here](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea).

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: de.undercouch#sbt-docbook-plugin;0.2-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      de.undercouch:sbt-docbook-plugin:0.2-SNAPSHOT (sbtVersion=0.11.2, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
[warn] 
[error] {file:/Users/ndidi/Sandbox/specs2-spring-examples/simple/project/plugins/}default-58af23/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: de.undercouch#sbt-docbook-plugin;0.2-SNAPSHOT: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? i
[warn] Ignoring load failure: no project loaded.
[error] Not a valid command: gen-idea
[error] gen-idea
[error]         ^
```

I've gone through the project's issues page and also Googled extensively, however I haven't discovered anyone else with this issue, causing me to believe that the problem is somewhat uncommon and likely to be related to an issue with my setup..

If anyone could shine a little light on this, it'd be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes have help resolve this and a number of other minor issues:

1. I removed this line:

   addSbtPlugin("de.undercouch" % "sbt-docbook-plugin" % "0.2-SNAPSHOT")

   from /project/plugins.sbt
2. I no longer run sbt commands from the commandline, I exclusively use the sbt console. That running *'$ sbt gen-idea'* fails, while *'> gen-idea'* in the sbt console succeeds, strikes me a somewhat odd. If I figure out why, I'll be sure to update with a comment.

Comment: The second step didn't work for me. I get `Not a valid command: gen-idea` from both cmdline and sbt console. Have you discovered any better solution?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by cleaning up the "~/.ivy2" and "~/.sbt" directories as suggested in [this thread](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/issues/177#issuecomment-9857676) on the sbt-idea official site.